# Why electric field in the given digram of an infinite charged conducting sheet not like the way i have drawn?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

[image]

In figure (A), book shows electric field lines just coming out of each face of the infinite sheet having charge perpendicular to area vector but I thought that the electric field lines which are anti parallel to area vector of both surfaces must also be there, which I tried to show in figure (B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single, infinitesimally thin sheet of charge, then the electric field is constant on either side pointing away from the sheet.

If you have two sheets of charge (with the same density), then in the region between the sheets, each sheet would creates an electric field of equal magnitude.  But since the directions of these fields are opposite, the total electric field is zero since the vectors cancel out.  So the electric field is zero anywhere between two infinite sheets of charge.

This is true regardless of whether the space between these two infinite sheets is vacuum or the interior of a conductor.

Comment: Thank you Sir for writing such a useful answer.

Comment: @Acuriousmind:  No problem!  If you found one of the answers (mine or someone else's) particularly useful, you should "accept" it by clicking on the check-mark logo to the left of that answer.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer by Michael Seifert is good, but I'll give a slightly different argument to show why your diagram (b) can't be correct.

Your diagram shows the E field pointing to the right in the left half of the sheet material, and to the left in the right half of the sheet. But Gauss's law (in the differential form) tells us that the E field can only change when the charge density is non-zero. Or put in a more hand-wavy way, that electric field lines can only terminate on charge.

So the field lines in your diagram to be correct, there must be a region of negative charge in the middle of the sheet. If the problem statement gives the location of all charge in the experiment, and no charge is given to be in the sheet center, then the field can't point one way in one half of the sheet and the other way in the other half.

Comment: Also the standard argument: If there is any leftover E field inside of a conductor, it would push charges around, making a countering E field, until no more E field is inside the conductor.

Comment: Thank you The Photon and @naturallyInconsistent your answers made my concepts more solid.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, I don't see that it's stated in the post that the material containing the sheet charges is a conductor (even if that is the easiest way to produce the given charge distribution in practice).

Comment: @ThePhoton question title says infinite charged conducting sheet.